# Select outgoing TCP/IP port on Android

Tags: android, networking, network-programming, tcp

Is there way select the outgoing port that I use when connecting, for example, to a web-service? I'll be working on a Android device so ideally something Java based would be easiest.

Comment: Why? There are few if any circumstances when you need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Socket.bind()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#bind%28java.net.SocketAddress%29) if you want to select local address and port, otherwise it is bound to one of local interfaces and the first available ephemeral port.

You may have to write your own HTTP UA implementation though if your HTTP client doesn't support `bind` and doesn't allow to provide your own socket

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I'm using ksoap2 to talk to a web-service, do you know of a higher level way to set the port?
For my own information can you point me to a link with a little more detail on 'ephemeral ports', I have a limited knowledge of the details of networking and it looks like it's relevant.